# Too much text pushes my buttons below the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

So I tried embedding my label (that has all the text) and buttons in a scrollView to perhaps be able to scroll down to them, but when I do that, everything just disappears.
[my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcb6k.png)

[my preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qy0l.png)

Just added some pictures as requested (thanks).
As for adding the scrollView (which may not be the optimal solution), I just selected all 4 buttons and the label, then selected "embed in scrollView". This led to a completely blank screen in preview.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? And any errors if any?

Comment: ScrollViews don't work with auto-layout below iOS 11 (currently in beta). The way to do it is to add a content-view (UIView) to the scrollview. Constrain the contentView to the scrollview's parent view and also to the scrollview itself. Add all subviews to the content-view and constrain them to the content-view: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/4671/uiscrollview-autolayout#t=201706220039112073119

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to fix the bottom constraints of your scrollview, so that the scrollview's frame does not extend past the bottom of the screen. You can then set constraints on the scrollView's content size to allow the user to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

From the storyboard image you posted, it looks like there isn't a bottom constraint. Select the scrollview in the storyboard, click the [pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4XmD.png) icon, and put in a number in for the bottom constraint (e.g. 0).